# Why doesn't the `tokio::join!` macro require the `await` keyword in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

In Rust (and other programming languages as well), the `await` keyword is used to indicate a suspension point in the body of an asynchronous function. However, I noted that contrary to other programming languages (Python `gather`, Swift `withTaskGroup`, JavaScript `Promise.all`, etc.), Rust does not require and will refuse the presence of an `await` after the `Tokyo::join!` macro.

For instance in this `async` function there is no `await` involved after `join!`:

```rust
use tokio::{io::Result, time::{sleep, Duration}, join};

async fn work() -> String {
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
    String::from("Work done")
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    println!("Awaiting…");
    let (o1, o2) = join!(
        work(),
        work(),
    );  // No `.await`
    println!("{}, {}", o1, o2);
    Ok(())
}
```

Is there a technical reason why the `join!` macro does not return some sort of aggregated `Future` or join handle that could be `await`ed on?

This implicit `await` is confusing since this asynchronous function appears to not have any suspension point at first sight (thus not requiring to be `async`) and I think that this may defeat the purpose of the `async-await` pattern that seeks to make suspension points explicit.

Comment: It is difficult to say _why_ but I'd guess that is because `select!` doesn't juse `await` either. And I seem to recall that even `select!` predates the `await` keyword.

Comment: So, likely historical reasons. Are you aware of discussions or threads about future directions of such async macros?

Comment: cause the await is IN the macro, select and join are kind of "dark magic" macro

Comment: Are you asking why it was designed this way (opinion-based, off topic) or why it can do that (because it is macro and it can insert the `.await` itself, unlike the functions you mentioned of the other languages)?

Comment: I'm more interested in the the technical reasons behind that choice and the implications on how to code properly in Rust given that: what is the goal/pros of not returning a future-like object? Would it cause issues (both for implementation and development) not to do so? I think this could be relevant for implementing async macros and other tools. For now, I don't know if its a subjective design choice (i.e. opinion-based) or a technical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expand the macro (this can be done on the Rust Playground with the Tools menu), you'll see code that looks like this:

```rust
let (o1, o2) = {
    // [some imports]
    let mut futures = (maybe_done(work()), maybe_done(work()));
    // [some more setup]
    poll_fn(move |cx| {
        // [innards]
    }).await
};
```

That `await` at the end is the only `await` in the expansion. So, there is no technical reason why the macro couldn't have been written to not contain the `await`. However, let's look at the history.

The `join` macro was introduced in [commit 7079bcd60975f592e08fcd575991f6ae2a409a1f](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/commit/7079bcd60975f592e08fcd575991f6ae2a409a1f) ([PR #2158](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/pull/2158)) and there wasn't much discussion there, but it had a predecessor in the `futures` library, introduced in [commit d67e2936c21a4d663814e38b06ce38d85bb02e9b](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/commit/d67e2936c21a4d663814e38b06ce38d85bb02e9b) ([PR #1051](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/pull/1051)) there.

One thing to note about that original implementation is that, unlike the one that is current in Tokio, it *is* heavily based on being inside an async context (the `poll!` and `pending!` macros depend on it):

```rust
...
loop {
    let mut all_done = true;
    $(
        if let ::core::task::Poll::Pending = poll!($fut.reborrow()) {
            all_done = false;
        }
    )*
...
```

Additionally, there was some discussion in the PR:

> **MajorBreakfast** commented on Jun 28, 2018
>
> - There probably should be some clear distinction between macros intended for use in async functions and other macros. Macros that internally use `await` should be marked somehow. Alternatively they could both use an `async` block and require an `await` around them `await!(join![a, b])`. This just looks so bad because `await!` is currently a macro, but it won't be in the future. The mental model is easier though and you could use it everywhere not just in async functions.

> **cramertj** commented on Jun 28, 2018
>
> @MajorBreakfast `select!` needs to do the `await!` internally (rather than providing a future as a result) in order to allow the compiler to be smarter about control-flow (e.g. allowing `return` to work normally, enabling the initialized-ness checks to understand the different conditions under which a break can occur, etc.). Since `select!` doessn't return a future, I thought it would be confusing for `join!` to return a future-- the two seem like somewhat natural doubles, and it seems surprising that they would work differently in that respect.

So, `select!` benefits from not introducing a new async block but incorporating itself into the caller's async block, and `join!` was designed to have the same character as `select!`, even though it itself does not benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the links to relevant discussions!